How do I trigger Case assignment rules on case edit operation? (Through UI)
I know basically case assignment rules trigger on insertion of case. but i have expectation of want to trigger the case assignment rules for the edit operation. can you please help me ?

on every edit? via automation or via user selection?

Thanks for the comment. on every edit through UI!

To force case assignment rules, enable the 'Default' checkbox and disable the "Show on edit page" checkbox under Case Assignment Checkbox. This will remove the ability for users to turn off case assignments when editing or creating a case. If both checkbox options are enabled, the Assignment checkbox is displayed when creating and editing a case and is checked by default.

Refer to this for more information: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385424&type=1
